# using a thumbnail viewer to display both the thumbnail and the enlarged image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

i have a .js file that shows thumbnails for images in a directory.  It is set to trigger on mouseover and show an enlarged image.  I need to modify this .js to show the thumbnail and the enlarged image on the same page in two different divisions when the page loads.

The code that triggers the .js is:

```
    <a href="http://www.marknutt.com/photos/storage/<?php echo $rows['file']; ?>" data-                         lightbox="" name="<?php echo '<b><i>'.$rows['painting'].'</i></b>'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'."<font color='#585858'>".$rows['year2'].'&nbsp;'    .$medb.' on.$rows['material2'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$pieces[0].' x '.$pieces[1].' x '.$pieces[2].'&nbsp;in.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
."<sup><font size=&quot;1&quot;>".$location2a.'</font></sup>&nbsp;'.$rows['location2'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$status3.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.
"<a id='displayText' href='javascript:toggle()'></font><font color=&quot;#31B404&quot;><i>Price</i></font></a><div id='toggleText' style='display: none' >&nbsp;&nbsp;".$pieces2a.$pieces2."</div>".
'<br>'.$markcom.'<br>'.$com.$query4d.'</a>'; ?>"

title="<?php echo $rows['painting']; ?>" 

onclick="return false"

style="max-width:70px;max-height:70px;" rel="enlargeimage2" 
rev="targetdiv:loadarea,link:http://www.marknutt.com/photos/storage/
<?php echo $rows['file']; ?>">
```

This pulls the images from the directory and displays them in a division with a one column table.  The rel="enlargeimage2" activates this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="thumbnailviewer_b.js"></script>
```

[ThumbnailViewer](http://www.marknutt.com/thumbnailviewer_b.js)

You can view this script in action by going to:

[Loading a thumbnail with large image](http://marknutt.com/indexmain12162013.php?name=Solanti)

Currently I must rolloever the thumbnail to enlarge it.  I know how to change this to a 'click' but not to load the enlarged image automatically when the page loads.  The ?name=Solanti in the url can be changed to any image filename.

I'm quickly learning jquery but still have a lot to learn.  Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#<yourImageID').fadeIn(1500); //fade image in once all the images (only 1?!) are loaded


})
```

This should do the trick and look nice because the image will fade in, instead of loading uglily.